# Specific number FORMAT mask like #,###,##0.0### that would force Excel GENERAL NUMBER format?

Tags: excel, business-intelligence, cognos

What custom format mask will display 3.0 as 3 and 3.10 as 3.1?

I am trying to support a Cognos report that uses custom SQL that selects from an Oracle column that is defined as NUMBER(11, 4). if I do not apply any formatting to the.1 column on the report, the resulting Excel column has "Number  " category formatting applied  with 4 decimals.

[image]

As a result, I see the following sample formatted values displayed:

```
a) 4,123.3400
b) 4.0123
c) 4.0100
d) 3
e) 0.10000
```

I would prefer to see only significant zeros afer the decimal point displayed. For example, 4.0100 should be 4.01 but otherwise the formatting is fine. When the number is a whole number, I prefer not to display a decimal point at all. For example, 3 is preferable to 3.0 for values with no fractional part.

I tried experimenting with custom formats and the closest that I can come to what I am looking or is this format

```
#,###,##0.0###
```

which produces:

```
a) 4,123.34
b) 4.0123
c) 4.01
d) 3.0
e) 0.1
```

There are two differences between using no format, the first example and my custom format:

1. Whole numbers are displayed with one zero after the decicimal (d)
2. Trailing insignificant zeros after the decimal are suppressed. (a)

What I woold like to see is the following, the difference with the opreceding example is that whole numbers are displayed without any decimal (d):

```
a) 4,123.34
b) 4.0123
c) 4.01
d) 3
e) 0.1
```

Excel acheives this by default with its "General" format, however, the trick is trying to get Cognos to produce that setting using custom SQL that selects from a NUMBER(11, 4) column. As mentioned above,  going with the default format results in Excel output that uses the General format but has 4 decimal places, so I get 4 decimals of precision if there is any faction part. The csolution appears to be to use a custom format.

Can my format

```
#,###,##0.0###
```

be tweeked to work like Excel's General format for numbers?

[image]

Comment: Did you try #,###,##0.####?

Comment: Yes, that will give me whole numbers that have a decimal, eg, 3.

Comment: Forgetting about Cognos, the only way you will get your desired format in Excel is (in Excel 2007+) with conditional formatting.  The two formats can be "#,##0"  or "#,##0.0########" (as many #'s after the decimal as you might possibly have use for).  In version prior to 2007, you'd need VBA, and you might run into a "too many formats" problem

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, you can't get all the formatting you want with one single format.

You should know that even Excel's General does not get everything you want, because that doesn't provide thousands separators.

You'll have to pick something to give up.  If you can give up the commas, then why not just use General?

Also note that you have superfluous `#` marks.  Your formatting is equivalent to `#,##0.0###`.

See [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/205759/format-a-number-with-optional-decimal-places-in-excel) for potential further ideas.

Comment: Your comment about superflous # marks was interesting. I thoughyt that I had to enter a sufficient number of # o reflect the max size of the number. As for your comment about going with the GENERAL format, if I had to choose I'd rather go with my custom format and retain the comma seperators but as mentioned in the post, when I do not apply formatting in Cognos BI but direct my output to Excel, I was surprised that the resulting formatting was not a plain GENERAL format. As a result, I even if i wanted to use a general format, I wouldn't know how to get there.

Comment: Well, where were you putting in your `#,###,##0.0###` format? If that format is being entered into Excel (if not by you directly, then presumably you have some way to indicate to Cognos to generate the Excel output using that format), then wherever you are putting that, you *should* be able to just put `General` instead, if you want Excel's General formatting.

Comment: See the updated question. I added images to show you where in Cognos I enter the format for the column. When I type in General for the format, I get the literal General in the output along with the value. If I specify DEFAULT from teh Format Type drop down, I get Number with 4 decimal places. I believe that Default is keying off of the data type of the column and this results in an EXCEL type of Number with 4 explicit decimal places.

Comment: So it seems Cognos isn't inserting your custom format verbatim into the resulting Excel file; it appears to be doing at least a little bit of preprocessing on it.  Well, I think that eliminates that possibility, then.

Comment: Oh, one last, desperate shot in the dark: I don't suppose you can tell Cognos to use custom format, but provide a blank as the pattern? (I'm going to guess that Cognos either doesn't let you do this, or it automatically reverts to its own default formatting.)